# How to set dyld_library_path in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, dylib, dyld

I am new to Xcode and Mac environment. I am using some dynamic and static libraries like boost, Clucene, etc. I have all the libraries under

> MyApp.app/Contents/Resources

I want to set this path as the app's dyld_library_path. I tried editing XXX.plist file like

> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH  /mypath/xxx

and setting the environment variable and argument in Xcode Nothing work.

but if I run a shell script like below without double clicking the app in my .dmg it works

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
cd /Volumes/xxx/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Volumes/xxx/myapp.app/Contents/Resources"
./myapp
```

I am sure this is not the proper way to do this. Is there proper way to set dyld_library_path every time I execute my app?

EDIT:
It also works if u mannualy copy all ur library to clients /usr/lib path... i guess this is also not a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 15):

Setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` isn't the best way to solve this problem. It's working around the fact that you've misinformed `dyld` as to where to find your libraries.

If you run `otool -L MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp` you'll see the paths to the libraries that MyApp wants to load. If any library isn't found at the specified path then `dyld` will look for the library in the locations specified by `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`. Setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` causes `dyld` to look for the library in the given locations ahead of the path that the `otool` command above returned.

The best way to solve this problem is to have your application specify the correct location of the libraries to start with so that setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not necessary. To do this you need to do the following:

1. Set the library identifier of each of the libraries that you're bundling inside your application to an `@rpath`-relative value. You can do this using `install_name_tool -id @rpath/libFoo.dylib libFoo.dylib`.
2. Add a Copy Files build phase to copy the libraries in to your application wrapper. `MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks` is a typical location. `MyApp.app/Contents/Resources` should be avoided since binaries aren't resources in the usual sense of the term.
3. Specify a run path search path when linking your application. This gives the linker a list of paths to use to resolve any `@rpath` variables that it encounters in any load commands. If you're copying the libraries to `MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks` you'll want to specify a run path search path of `@loader_path/../Frameworks`. You can do this via the `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` (Runpath Search Paths) configuration setting in Xcode on your application target.

After doing all this you should be able to re-run the `otool` command mentioned above and see that the paths to your library are using `@rpath`-relative paths. You should then be able to run `otool -lV MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp` and see an `LC_RPATH` load command specified with a value of `@loader_path/../Frameworks`. Finally, you should be able to run your application and see that it finds the libraries within its Frameworks directory without having `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` set!

Comment: Setting LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS (Runpath Search Paths) was the key for me.