# dyld library error while using cocoapods to add testing library

Tags: cocoa, cocoapods

I'm trying to install a testing library for a project on top of SenTestingKit. 
Prior to installing, the project builds fine and runs the test suite using SenTestingKit. 
However, after using cocoapods to install another testing framework like Specta or Kiwi (which apparently depend on SenTestingKit), the project builds, but then immediately throws this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SenTestingKit.framework/Versions/A/SenTestingKit
  Referenced from: [...]
  Reason: image not found
```

I've tried about a dozen different suggestions from people with similar problems (changing the target build settings test host, changing the target framework search paths, etc, making sure pods are configured for the test target, etc.), all to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally tracked down the answer. 
Following the steps laid out in the answer here fixed the issue:
[How to set dyld_library_path in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888668/how-to-set-dyld-library-path-in-xcode)

Answer (score 2):

Try with the following steps to link the static library to our project (which inturn uses a framework or static library):

1. Include the static library  in the main projects "link binary with library".
2. Provided the header path at HEADER_SEARCH_PATH as well as LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH (Inside Build Settings of app's target).

**Most important:**
In the target's build phases - > Link binaries with libraries set the relevant framework (SenTestKit.framework in our case) to "Optional" instead of "Required".

Hope this will fix your issue